# Configure SharePoint Search to Look into Video Transcripts

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, media-streaming

We are looking to make SharePoint the "go to" place for finding any content within the company.

Such content would include video files and, especially - transcripts.

Microsoft Stream does exhibit the right abilities to search through transcripts across all videos in Stream and we find that very useful.

However, we would like that Stream content to be accessible via a SharePoint search, more specifically, we would like searching to include video transcripts and ability to jump to a Stream result straight from
a SharePoint search.

Can someone offer any guidelines on how to achive something like that?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I known this is not supported in SharePoint online search.

Currently only embedded Videos from Stream in site pages should be integrated in search results.

Related User Voice:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330321-sharepoint-search/suggestions/41412847-find-ms-stream-video-in-sharepoint-search-results